# Protonic emissions

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, protons

In a beta emission a neutron decays,into a proton and an electron, and an electron randomly gets ejected from the nucleus due to the phenomenon of barrier tunnelling(correct me if am wrong).But why is this phenomenon restricted to only the electron? Is there a law which restricts a proton from exiting the nucleus during the decay, or the energy gained is too small, or is it that the probability is just too low for a proton to to cross the energy barrier via barrier tunnelling?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_beta_decay

Comment: The reason for the decay is that converting a neutron into a proton produces a more stable daughter nucleus.  Ejection of the resulting proton would result in a less stable daughter nucleus.  The electron (and neutrino) are just by-products of the decay and do not contribute to the stability of the daughter nucleus.

Comment: In addition to energy conservation there are quantum numbers to be conserved, charge, spin, parity, angular momentum and momentum too. This affects the probabilities . The neutron decays weakly  into a three body decay, e p e_neutrino. A proton can turn into a neutron by electron capture if the energetics allow. for the energy levels look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model